# How to use socat for capturing unix domain socket packets sent by a specific process?

Tags: unix-socket, socat

I came across this gist https://gist.github.com/ranjithum/274b921eed36d2e98c204f43aaf53ca3 which allows me to capture packets over unix domain sockets.

But i have bit of unusual requirement, i have unix server which is receiving packets from multiple clients.

Is it possible to receive packets only from a specific client ? (or is possible to specify pid of a client process)

There is entry in man page

```
       pid_t  A number, read with strtol() , specifying a process id.
```

But i haven't come across any examples.